# Jenkins job status failing despite running correctly

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a jenkins jobs that executes with 'Publish over SSH'. The job connects to the remote server, transfers files and runs and ansible playbook. [image]

The playbook runs as intended, confirmed by the logs. However at the end of the job an error is returned, failing the job. It's causing problems as it's preventing the pipeline from working correctly.

```
SSH: EXEC: completed after 402,593 ms
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [server] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [2]]
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
[Run Playbook] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins1528195779014969962.sh
+ echo Finished
Finished
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Is there a setting missing to allow this to pass?

Answer (score 0):

never used the 'Publish over SSH' you are referingto, but I can recommend Jenkins [Ansible Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ansible+Plugin). I am running several playbooks in pipeline stages here successfully from labeled build slaves (have one dedicated slave that has Ansible installed) targeting Linux hosts on cloud infrastructure via SSH.

Especially in combination with the [ANSI color plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Ansible+Plugin#AnsiblePlugin-ColorizedOutput) the output very readable.

If you cannot try that plugin, check whats the return code of the playbook run shell call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried the Jenkins Ansible Plugin previously, but I couldn't find any way to run it on a remote host? Likely that I've missed something though

Comment: have a look at that sample: ` 
ansiblePlaybook(
  inventory: 'hosts',
  playbook: '${PLAYBOOK}.yml',
  credentialsId: '${SSH_KEY}',
  extraVars: [
      target: '${SSH_TARGETHOST}'
   ],
   vaultCredentialsId: 'ansible-vault' `